# Decomposing a sum (Expected Loss)

Tags: mathematical-statistics

I am struggling to find a way to decompose this sum. This formula comes from the risk management world and it is used to compute the expected loss for an obligor i:

$\sum_{i=1}^{n}PD_i*EAD_i*LGD_i$

Where, $PD_i$ is expressed as a percentage going from [0,1], LGD is expressed a percentage going from [0,1] and $EAD_i$ is an arbitrary amount of money so it can take any value in $\mathbb{R^+}$. I have looked carefully in the general manipulations for finite sums but none seems to satisfy my needs. I already know that this is not valid:

$\sum_{i=1}^{n}PD_i*EAD_i*LGD_i \neq\sum_{i=1}^{n}PD_i+\sum_{i=1}^{n}EAD_i +\sum_{i=1}^{n}LGD_i$

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by "decomposing" a sum?  What exactly are the "needs" to which you refer?  Why do you need some kind of decomposition?  (The sum itself looks particularly efficient to compute, easy to program, and simple to analyze mathematically.)

Comment: Hello whuber ! Thank you for your question. I would like to decompose it because doing it would help me understand how portfolio expected losses are linked with individual obligor expected losses in a mathematical way. To be more precise when working with portfolios of obligors you do the following: 

$EL_p = \sum_{i=1}^{n} EL_i = \sum_{i=1}^{n}PD_iLGD_iEAD_i$

Comment: But then then if I would like to find the $PD_p$ of the portfolio, it is not simply the sum of the $PD_i$ for each individual borrower i: 

$PD_p \neq \sum_{i=1}^{n}PD_i$

The same thing happnes to $LDG$. On the other hand, $EAD_p$ is simply the sum of the $EAD_i$. 
Therefore, I believe that there is a way to decompose this sum in order to get the mathematical representation of the $PD_p$ and the $LGD_p$ and so write down: 

$EL_p = PD_P*LGD_p*EAD_p$ instead of using the previous formula.

Have I managed to be clear and explain my struggle? 

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

First, this formula got popularized by [Basel capital adequacy framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_III). It's a very crude way of looking at the expected losses, to start with. For instance, why would the PD and LGD be independent, as it is implied in the formula? Imagine, it's a mortgage, your likelihood to default would probably be dependent on the same factors as the loss amount given you defaulted. The home price is one such factor. If you bought a house to flip it (sell at higher price), then when the prices drop you're likely to default, and the loss will be dependent on the price too.

Second, if you subscribe to this silly formula, then the question is how to add up the expected losses if there is correlation between the obligors in a portfolio. When the home price falls, all the mortgages will be more likely to default. This is a systematic component. On the other hand, they are not going to default at once, so there is a idiosyncratic component, which brings the diversification benefit. In Basel the way people handle the diversification benefit is through some kind of a coeficient $r$:
$$Loss=r\sum_i Loss_i$$, you can estimate this $r$ somehow. I don't see the reason to do more complicated analysis because the whole PD,LGD,EAD thing is so crude to start with. T

Answer (score 0):

This paper answers your question:

Hunt, C.; Taplin, R. Aggregation of Incidence and Intensity Risk Variables to Achieve Reconciliation. Risks 2019, 7, 107

pdf download free from: https://www.mdpi.com/2227-9091/7/4/107

In brief, EAD is aggregated by simple summation, whereas PD and LGD are aggregated per a new kind of "mean" that we have proposed, such that the product EAD * PD * LGD of these aggregates does exactly reconcile to the correct total EL - or, interpreted using your words: the total EL is *decomposed* as the product of these three aggregates.